# scatterplot with points based on color and size of factor in ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I'm new to ggplot2 so please bear with me. I would like to make a scatter plot in ggplot2 where I can color the data OR change the size of the points based on a second variable factor. I am able to do this for color using the plot() function as so:

```
#simulate data
x1 <- rnorm(100)
y <- as.factor(runif(100)<=.70)
df <- data.frame(x1,y)
#plot
plot(df$x1, col = df$y,cex = 1, pch = 19)
```

And this is my attempt with ggplot2:

```
qplot(seq_along(df$x1), df$x1) + scale_colour_manual(breaks = df$y)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the expected output by specifying the color and shape in `col` and `shape` in `aes`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x1, y=seq(1,length(x1)),col=y, shape=y)) + geom_point()
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question has a title: *scatterplot with points based on **color** and **shape** of factor in ggplot 2*

whereas the text in the question says: *...where I can color the data OR change the size of the points...*

So what are you looking for? Colour, shape or size?

You can use `shape`,`size` and `colour` argument in `ggplot()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=seq(1,length(x1)), y=x1,colour=y, size=y)) + geom_point()
```

In this example i just set up that the size (`size=...`) and colour (`color=...`) should depend on y variable, but you can change it however you want. For the shape argument just use `shape=...`

**However: Using size for a discrete variable is not advised.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted. Using size for discrete variables is not advised but it's a good way to plot extremely unbalanced data. If you know any other ways to visualize highly unbalanced data (where one level of the factor is < 1% of the data), then I would love to hear it. Cheers